# Xamarin iOS, how to save a video and play it from a file

Tags: ios, video, xamarin.ios

I am able to record a video and save it with:

`var doc = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string filename = Path.GetRandomFileName () + ".mov";
var videopath = Path.Combine (doc, filename);`

^ That's the video path I am saving it to but I can't find how to play the video from the file.

```
mp = new MPMoviePlayerController(NSUrl.FromFilename("Movies/Showhouzreel2music.m4v"));
```

^ I have tried this and can see this video file and play it, but this video was placed by me and won't work for the video I have taken.

I would love any directions or help you guys can give.

Thank you and if you need any more information, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You said you can get MPMoviePlayerController working with a file you placed?

If so then just try this.

```
string newVideoPath = Path.GetFileName(videopath);
mp = new MPMoviePlayerController(NSUrl.FromFilename(newVideoPath));
```

---

EDIT (More elaborate answer):

Implement something like this.

```
public void PlayVideo(string videopath)
    {
        string name = Path.GetFileName(videopath);
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            QLPreviewItemFileSystem prevItem = new QLPreviewItemFileSystem(name, videopath);
            QLPreviewController previewController = new QLPreviewController();
            previewController.DataSource = new PreviewControllerDS(prevItem);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(previewController, true, null);
        });
    }

    public class PreviewControllerDS : QLPreviewControllerDataSource
    {
        private QLPreviewItem _item;

        public PreviewControllerDS(QLPreviewItem item)
        {
            _item = item;
        }

        public override IQLPreviewItem GetPreviewItem(QLPreviewController controller, nint index)
        {
            return _item;
        }

        public override nint PreviewItemCount(QLPreviewController controller)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public class QLPreviewItemFileSystem : QLPreviewItem
    {
        string _fileName, _filePath;

        public QLPreviewItemFileSystem(string fileName, string filePath)
        {
            _fileName = fileName;
            _filePath = filePath;
        }

        public override string ItemTitle
        {
            get
            {
                return _fileName;
            }
        }
        public override NSUrl ItemUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return NSUrl.FromFilename(_filePath);
            }
        }

    }
```

And whenever you need to call it use this:

```
PlayVideo(videopath);
```

This will also allow you to open up other files should you choose to in the future. (Like pdfs, images, etc.) Note: You might have to modify some code to get it to work, as I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: Edit: You really should be using AVPlayer though, as  MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated in iOS9 and up. Please read the documentation for examples:
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/play_a_video_using_avplayer/

Comment: just got a question, for videopath are you you just putting the name of the video you looking for or the whole video path, I can't get it to work for either. I am trying to get the video I all ready placed.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/MoviePlayback/ 
this is how I playing back the video. maybe this bad way of playing back video, is the issue

Comment: hey I tried it but I not got it to work. do you have any example or more that you can, show me.

Comment: @oisin1min Ok, what exactly isn't working? Are you getting error messages? Blank screens? Nothing happens when you push a button? I need more information about what's happening in order to help you :)
Please also specify whether the errors are happening with the original code, or with the code provided in the answer.

Comment: sorry for the short message, I just wanted to try some thing. when I run the code you give me. I get a screen with with he file name and below that is say "quicktime movie ". it like it treating it file and rather than a video. maybe this because I of where I am saving the video.

Comment: @oisin1min Ok but you still have a share button that you can use, correct? If so then you could try to save it in the Personal folder instead of the documents folder, and also maybe try saving it with a different file type.

Comment: @gerrib99 yeah the share is there but does not work. I tried changing the file type and I can't record with different file type and for reading does not seem to change any thing. to be honest I am stumped  about what to try next.

Comment: @oisin1min That tells me that there is probably something wrong with the video file itself, and not with opening the file, because this code should work. What code are you using to record?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios10/AVCam/ this the example I am working off. removed the camera part but that the basic code I am working off.

Comment: If I were you I would try to implement James Montemagno's Media Plugin. It makes things much easier. It's written for Xam-Forms but I'm sure it'll work for Xam-iOS as well. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin